# What is the issue in the Google map engine Query

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-engine

i need to query some data with where clause

as per the API [google map engine](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/read#sql_queries) i have request as below.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/tables/14538994882799551513-11853667273131550346/features?where=gx_id%3D900
```

for the above URL it says BAD REQUEST **where=gx_id=900**

and the response is

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "The value is invalid.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "query"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The value is invalid."
 }
}
```

Please suggest me what is wrong in this URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a Number in your query, but the particular `gx_id` seems to be of type String.

Enclose the Number with single-quotes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/tables/14538994882799551513-11853667273131550346/features?where=gx_id%3D%27900%27
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you don't have to worry about creating and keeping track of your ID's. the [API](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/best-practices#creating_ids) says you need to include gx_id only to make sure that no Feature is sent twice.
Therefore, you can just throw in a string representing your system's current time for example.